# How can a cloud-hosted Windows Server 2012 run on 500 MB RAM?

Tags: memory, windows-server-2012, hosting

I have seen Windows Server 2012 cloud hosting with 500 MB of RAM.

How can Windows Server 2012 run with only 500 MB of RAM at all? What does it mean if not the actual RAM given to the operating system?

Update : example here http://www.burst.net/winvps.php

Comment: What exactly is "500 Mo of Ram"?  Do you mean 500mb of Ram?  Can you provide a link to where you read about this restriction?  Did you mistakenly read about where you can provide 500mb of cloud storage space with Windows 2012 server, and think that this was about system Ram instead?  Or are you talking about how the Minimum Required amount of Ram for the most basic limited version (aka Windows Server 2012 Foundation) is only 512mb?  Because that minimum is only for Foundation.

Comment: @BonGart I'm pretty sure the "o" is supposed to stand for "octet" in this case, as in eight (oct) bits. So Mo and MB would be equivalent. I *think* that in French "octet" is often used instead of "byte", for example.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I didn't know that.  Cool

Comment: Without a link to where you saw that claim it is impossible to give an accurate answer without making assumptions. This could be a stupid host not giving you enough to do what you want, or it could be 512 for your application's use and the OS has a separate pool, we need more context.

Comment: The host In question is a scam there isn't anyway they can afford Windows Server 2012 VM for $8 a month and not charge you for the license.  Furthermore the question makes no sense... WS2012 functions fine on 512MB

Answer (score 1):

It usually means that you are given the environment of the operating system and 500MB of memory for your applications, web applications, server applications, services, and so on.